# regex to strictly check alphanumeric and special character

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters, alphanumeric

To check alphanumeric with special characters

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_$@.]{8,15}$/;
   return regex.test(pass);
```

But, above regex returns `true` even I pass following combination

`asghlkyudet`

`78346709tr`

`jkdg7683786`

But, I want that, it must have alphanumeric and special character otherwise it must return false for any case. Ex:

`fg56_fg$`

`Sghdfi@90`

Comment: You have the underscore withing the regexp parameters.

Comment: yes.. i considered underscore as special character

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe some more examples of what you want to return false.

Comment: only accept alphanumeric and special character,which is mentioned in the regex expression other than that it should return false. I have also mentioned two example for right input and 3 example of wrong input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `a-zA-Z0-9_` with `\w`, and using two anchored look-aheads - one for a special and one for a non-special, the briefest way to express it is:

```
/^(?=.*[_$@.])(?=.*[^_$@.])[\w$@.]{8,15}$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Use look-ahead to check that the string has at least one alphanumeric character and at least one special character:

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*[_$@.])[a-zA-Z0-9_$@.]{8,15}$/
```

By the way, the set of special characters is too small. Even consider the set of ASCII characters, this is not even all the special characters.

Answer (score -1):

The dollar sign is a reserved character for Regexes. You need to escape it.

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_/$@.]{8,15}$/;
```

Comment: sorry, its not helpful